Error Getting TOken : ('invalid_grant: Invalid JWT Signature.', {'error': 'invalid_grant', 'error_description': 'Invalid JWT Signature.'})
I don't understand why I am getting this error every time while generating a bearer token for Firebase Messaging V1s Api .
def Generate Token():
        try:
            SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging']
            SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'api', 'service-account.json')
            
            # Load the service account credentials
            credentials =            service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE,scopes=SCOPES)
            credentials.refresh(Request())
            
            return credentials.token
        except Exception as e:
            return "Error Getting TOken : "+ str(e)

In the above Django View Function i am trying to get the Bearer token but i am getting this error :

Access Toke : Error Getting TOken : ('invalid_grant: Invalid JWT Signature.', {'error': 'invalid_grant', 'error_description': 'Invalid JWT Signature.'})


Response status code: 401
Response data: {'error': {'code': 401, 'message': 'Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.', 'status': 'UNAUTHENTICATED'}}`

while generating and using it to send Notification.
I don't understand why this error is coming and how can i overcome it?

Sounds like your service account is somehow wrong.  There's not much we can do to fix that for you.  Make sure you're using the right one.

Yes my Service Account was wrong , when made new private key it worked and send the notification to device_token ,
but now i am getting new problem , Which i dont know how to set 'FIrebase-messaging-sw.js' ,
in my current FIrebase-messagin-sw.js file , i was getting error
as
firebase-messaging-sw.js:5  Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': The script at 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-app-compat.js' failed to load.
at http://localhost:3000/firebase-messaging-sw.js:5:1
help me if you can
Sorry for format i am new

If you have a new problem, post it separately.  Stack Overflow doesn't support going back and forth on new problems in comments.
